# Web app to manage subscriptions to online magazine

Tags: wordpress, cms, looking-for-a-script

I'm looking for a php web app, a Wordpress plugin, or an online web service (naturally as cheap as possible) to **manage the subscriptions** for an **online magazine**.
These are the main features I need:

- register/open new subscription
- renew subscription
- pay online with credit card
- send automatic emails after registration
- auto-send reminder when subscription expires
- send bulk emails to all subscribers

The magazine runs on Wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

How about a membership plugin? There are a few. [WPmember](http://wp-member.com/) or I think [wpmu](http://wpmu.org/) has a plugin like this. I Think wpmember can do all of the things you are looking for.